# Why are alternating blank rows appearing in my GridView?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

All of this is fairly new to me, so I apologize if these are dumb questions.

1 - The table that my GridView is pulling from contains no blank rows, so why is every other row in my GridView blank?  See my HTML and C# code below:

2 - I can't seem to get the dates to format correctly.  Usually, I just insert DataFormatString: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" into each date row for the GridView.  That isn't working.  The dates are returning in a "YYYY-DD-MMT00:00:00-06:00" format.  I realize this has something to do with JSON, but how do I make the dates return in a "MM/DD/YYYY" format?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="ASPSnippets_Pager.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            GetC(1);
        });
        $("[id*=txtC]").live("keyup", function () {
            GetC(parseInt(1));
        });
        $(".Pager .page").live("click", function () {
            GetC(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
        });
        function SearchTerm() {
            return jQuery.trim($("[id*=txtC]").val());
        };
        function GetC(pageIndex) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetC",
                data: '{searchTerm: "' + SearchTerm() + '", pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        var row;
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var c = xml.find("C");
            if (row == null) {
                row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            }
            $("[id*=GridView1] tr").not($("[id*=GridView1] tr:first-child")).remove();
            if (c.length > 0) {
                $.each(company, function () {
                    var company = $(this);
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("A").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("B").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("C").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("D").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(5).html($(this).find("E").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(6).html($(this).find("F").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(7).html($(this).find("G").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(8).html($(this).find("H").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(9).html($(this).find("I").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(10).html($(this).find("DateApproved").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(11).html($(this).find("J").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(12).html($(this).find("K").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(13).html($(this).find("L").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(14).html($(this).find("M").text());
                    $("[id*=GridView1]").append(row);
                    row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });
                var pager = xml.find("Pager");
                $(".Pager").ASPSnippets_Pager({
                    ActiveCssClass: "current",
                    PagerCssClass: "pager",
                    PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
                    PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
                    RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
                });
                $(".Company").each(function () {
                    var searchPattern = new RegExp('(' + SearchTerm() + ')', 'ig');
                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(searchPattern, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + SearchTerm() + "</span>"));
                });
            } else {
                var empty_row = row.clone(true);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("colspan", $("td", row).length);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("align", "center");
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).html("No records found for the search criteria.");
                $("td", empty_row).not($("td:first-child", empty_row)).remove();
                $("[id*=GridView1]").append(empty_row);
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table style="font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Book'">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #273B69; text-align: center" class="auto-style1">
                    <h1 class="auto-style2"><span class="auto-style3"></span>
                    </h1>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #D8D8D8;" class="auto-style8">
                    <h3>

                    </h3>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top" class="auto-style7">
                    <h5 class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
                            runat="server" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            Font-Names="Franklin Gothic Book" 
                            Font-Size="Small" 
                            CellPadding="4" 
                            ForeColor="#333333" 
                            GridLines="Both" 
                            BorderWidth="1px" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="A" HeaderText="A" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="B" HeaderText="B" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="C" HeaderText="C" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="D" HeaderText="D" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="E" HeaderText="E" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="F" HeaderText="F" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="G" HeaderText="G" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="H" HeaderText="H" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="I" HeaderText="I" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="J" HeaderText="J" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="K" HeaderText="K" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="L" HeaderText="L" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="M" HeaderText="M" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="N" HeaderText="N" Visible="false" />
                            </Columns>
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                        </asp:GridView>

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static int PageSize = 10;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDummyRow();
        }
    }

    private void BindDummyRow()
    {
        DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
        dummy.Columns.Add("A");
        dummy.Columns.Add("B");
        dummy.Columns.Add("C");
        dummy.Columns.Add("D");
        dummy.Columns.Add("E");
        dummy.Columns.Add("F");
        dummy.Columns.Add("G");
        dummy.Columns.Add("H");
        dummy.Columns.Add("I");
        dummy.Columns.Add("J");
        dummy.Columns.Add("K");
        dummy.Columns.Add("L");
        dummy.Columns.Add("M");
        dummy.Columns.Add("N");
        dummy.Rows.Add();
        GridView1.DataSource = dummy;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetC(string searchTerm, int pageIndex)
    {
        string query = "[GetC_Pager]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", searchTerm);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", pageIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", PageSize);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        return GetData(cmd, pageIndex).GetXml();
    }

    private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd, int pageIndex)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XYZConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds, "C");
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Pager");
                    dt.Columns.Add("PageIndex");
                    dt.Columns.Add("PageSize");
                    dt.Columns.Add("RecordCount");
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    dt.Rows[0]["PageIndex"] = pageIndex;
                    dt.Rows[0]["PageSize"] = PageSize;
                    dt.Rows[0]["RecordCount"] = cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value;
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: The code works.  I just want to know why alternating blank rows are appearing.  As stated in my first sentence, I am completely new to this.